# Is this a selection Sort or Insertion sort? Please give me right direction

Tags: c, sorting, insertion-sort, selection-sort

```
void main()
{
  char name[5][10],temp[10];
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 printf("\nEnter the name of student:");
 scanf("%s",name[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<(5-1);i++)
{
  for(j=i+1;j<5;j++)
  {
    if(strcmp(name[i],name[j])>0)
  {
    strcpy(temp,name[i]);
    strcpy(name[i],name[j]);
    strcpy(name[j],temp);
   }
  }
}
printf("\n the name of student is:");
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 printf("\n%s",name[i]);
}
 getch();
}
```

I couldn't figure out the difference between insertion sort and selection sort ..Is this code following selection algorithm or Insertion ?

Comment: Just to note - I imagine having the swap operation consist of 3 `strcpy`'s (as above) would lead to a rather slow sort (not that this sort is fast enough that it's used in practice to start with, but that's beside the point). The usual idea is just to swap pointers (unless you're dealing with primitives).

Comment: @Armin: It is not a bubble sort. Note that he compares/swaps non-contiguous elements.

Comment: @comocomocomocomo It's a horrible mutation.

Comment: @Armin "It's a horrible mutation". Yes, but it behaves like selection sort, if we don't take into account the unnecessary swaps. Besides, I've seen worse things (both loops iterating through the whole array...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a specially slow version of selection sort.

It looks like a bubble sort, but a bubble sort would compare/swap the elements at positions `j-1` and `j`, which are contiguous. You compare/swap the elements at positions `i` and `j`.

During every iteration of the outer loop, `i` remains constant while `j` advances from `i+1` to the end. Thus, you end up having the element with the minimum value at position `i`.

You probably make a lot of unnecessary movements. A proper selection sort would search for the minimum value without moving anything. Then it would swap that minimum value with the value at position `i`. Therefore, it would perform only one swap per element in the array.